# Rasterize vector to presence-absence raster incorrect in R

Tags: r, error, rasterization

I want to create a presence-absence raster out of a shapefile (vector) with the rasterize command of the R-package in R. Until now I only get wrong results.

The raster should just distinguish between the two options ('shapefile on this cell present', 'shapefile on this cell abscent').

I tried it out with several options of the rasterize-command:

```
forest_polygons_raster_mask <- rasterize(forest_polygons, ras, mask = TRUE)

forest_polygons_raster_update <- rasterize(forest_polygons, ras, update =  
TRUE)

forest_polygons_raster_cov <- rasterize(forest_polygons, ras, getCover = 
TRUE)
```

the command with the getCover option does not stop, also after several hours. With both of the other commands I get a wrong result and my raster has presence-cells in areas where the shapefile is abscent.

The original shapefile with two holes:
[image: :]

That is the raster I get after the rasterize command with the update-option. One hole is missing, and the other is split into two smaller holes. No abscence was recognized wrong, just presence was recognized wrong:
[image]

Shapefile layer over raster layer, the holes in the shapefile are not left out as abscence in the raster:
[image]

Did anyone have a similar problem? What might the problem be? My shapefile is quite ordinary with different fields of the categories: ID, Shape (Polygon), Classification (text), Shape_Area, Shape_Length.
The cellsize of the input raster for the rasterize process is quite small (so I do not expect that the errors are due to two big cells).

Comment: Not sure we can help without getting your data - is that possible? Or something that shows the same problem?

Comment: Yes, I completely see your point. Unfortunately it is sensitive data, so I cannot share it and I have never found a similar problem in any other data...

Comment: Without your original data it is tough to figure out what is going on - long run times may be an indication of geometry problems though, have you checked the validity of your vector data?

Answer (score 1):

The option that uses `getCover = TRUE` is correct, but:

1. This option returns the proportion of cell covered by polygon. So the raster values have a range between 1 and 0 so you can check these values that are greater than 0, but given these magnitude and the R color scales, they seem to be 0 (black).
2. This option returns 0 as background.
3. You should change values greater than 0 to 1:

   ```
   forest_polygons_raster_cov[forest_polygons_raster_cov[] > 0] <- 1
   ```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I will try it out and update this thread how it worked out!

Comment: Unfortunately the process with getCover = True seems to not run through. With mask or update = True the runtime is about 2-3 hours. With getCover it did not finish after approximately 17 hours now, even though I parallelized it... Do you have any ideas what the problem is with getCover = True?

Comment: Can you provide example files?  `getCover = TRUE` split each pixel into 100 parts and calculate the percentage. This makes the processing process even slower.